# Post Process Collection.remove on the server

Tags: meteor

I would like to post process collection.remove on the server, but not sure how to accomplish this. The usecase: A collection contains a reference to a file on the filesystem, which needs to be removed when the document is removed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways you can do this:

#### use a method

If you use a method to remove the document, you can also remove the file as a side effect. For example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  removePost: function(postId) {
    Posts.remove(postId);
    removeFileForPost(postId);
  }
});
```

#### use a hook

Have a look at the [collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/package/collection-hooks) package. You can clean up the file in the `after.remove` function.